# DustJS extend layout?

Tags: node.js, dust.js

In Jade JS, it's very easy to extend a layout. Supposed one have layout.jade, and for the index.jade, just do:

```
extend layout

block content // content comes here
```

Then it's pretty sufficient.

I searched the [official guide](https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs) but didn't found how to do. The most similar seems to be something like:

```
{>partials}
```

But still that's not **extending** a layout. How to achieve similar thing in DustJS? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... turns out I didn't read the dust documents careful enough.

Layout File:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{+title}Location of Title{/title}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="page-title" class="very-middle">{+title}Title Comes Here{/title}</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    {+content}
    Content Comes Here
    {/content}
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Content File:

```
 {>layout/}

 {<content}
   {!
     Content simply comes here
   }
 {/content}
```

So the point is the use of {+placeHolder}, {>toExtend} and {